# convert response from api to object with specific format

Tags: javascript

I have this response from api

```
columns: Array(4)
0: "Id"
1: "Title"
2: "Description"
3: "IsActive"
```

and I need to convert it to this format, so there will "fields" and under the fields it list down the values from the api response and on each value there will be type which I need to determine also if it's Id or IsActive then it will be number. I'm only allow to follow this specific object format and also I need to support IE browser

```
fields: {
Id: { type: "number" },
Title: { type: "string" },
Description: { type: "string" },
IsActive: { type: "number" }
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried yourself?

Comment: I tried using this but no idea on how to create specifc format`     var columnNames = Object.keys(columns).map(function (key) {
                    return {
                        fields: columns[key]
                    }
                }); `

Comment: @ScottSauyet I also tried this     return {
                        fields: {columns[key]:{type:{''}} }
                    } but looks like the syntax is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the additional information about which types are numeric somewhere.  This solution stores those in an array, passes this array into a function, and gets back a function which takes an array of columns and returns an object of field definitions.

```js
const makeFields = (numericTypes) => (columns) => columns.reduce(
  (a, s) => ({...a, [s]: {type: numericTypes.includes(s) ? 'numeric' : 'string'}}),
  {}
)

const numericTypes = ['Id', "IsActive"]
const columns = ["Id", "Title", "Description", "IsActive"]

console.log(makeFields(numericTypes)(columns))
```

You can save that intermediate function with something like `const makeMyFields = makeFields(numericTypes)` and then later using it as `makeMyFields(columns)`

## Update

Here is another version that should work in IE (untested):

```js
const makeFields = function(numericTypes) {
  return function(columns) {
    return columns.reduce(function(a, s) {
      a[s] = {type: numericTypes.includes(s) ? 'numeric' : 'string'}
      return a
    }, {})
  }
}
```

## Update 2

You were having problems running this code.  I'm guessing that you supplied the parameters incorrectly.  Note that this version required you to pass the list of numeric values to get back a function you would then call with the list of columns to get back an object of the types.  That is, you had to call it like this:

```
// makeFields (numericTypes) (columns)
//    ^            ^             ^------ call that new function with column names
//    |             `---- call with list of numeric types, returns a new function
//     `-- function name
```

It's easy enough to change the function so that you can supply all the parameters in one go.  But there is an advantage to that formulation.  You can call the outer function with the numeric types and get back a reusable function.  That inner function can then be applied to any set of columns you choose.  It could be passed, say, to `map`, so that if you had multiple sets of columns, you could simply write `multipleColumns.map(makeFields(numericTypes))`.

But if you want to change it, the new version might look like this:

```js
const makeFields = function(numericTypes, columns) {
  return columns.reduce(function(a, s) {
    a[s] = {type: numericTypes.includes(s) ? 'numeric' : 'string'}
    return a
  }, {})
}

const numericTypes = ['Id', "IsActive"]
const columns = ["Id", "Title", "Description", "IsActive"]

console.log(makeFields(numericTypes, columns))
```

Comment: Thanks Scott for the help, I'm trying it right now but looks like the arrow function is not being recognize, I google and it says that arrow function will not work in IE? Is that correct? Or I'm just missing something on my visual studio

Comment: You did mention IE, but I've gotten out of the habit of thinking too much about its quirks, by using Babel to transpile code like this.  It's easy enough to rewrite with function declarations or function expressions.

Comment: Update added to handle IE.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I tried to convert it but I got stack on (a, s) => ({...a, [s], I will try it, appreciate the help

Comment: In my update above, I actually  modified the accumulator in place.  I generally don't like to do that, but it's probably harmless as it gets reinitialized between calls.

Comment: Not sure what went wrong but when I tried to display the result in console, it just display the function code block and I'm not getting any error maybe I'll just continue tomorrow, need to sleep, thanks a lot Scott, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: One more update shows how to fix what I think likely went wrong for you, either by changing the way you call the function or by slightly rewriting the function.